# Is it possible to group a table based on the condition in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, select

I have table 'request' and I need to somehow group the table where the flag 'is_applicant' = 1 if exiting rows with the same 'id_request' and 'the same id_user'
you can see it better by example...

[image: enter image description re]

I need to get this...
[image]

Thank you for the answer or advice how to achieve this, I need it to display the request to a specific user in php. :)

Comment: Sample data must be provided as textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Desired output must match sample data strictly. Precise MySQL version must be provided.

Comment: It doesn't do what it should, if there are two rows that have the same id_request value and also is_user (is_applicant is always 1 or 0 ), then only the row with is_applicant = 1 is displayed. If there are multiple rows with the same id_request but different is_user, then all these rows will be displayedTL:DR - there will always be only one row with the same id_request value and the same id_user value (vic. comparison of both tables).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id_request,
        MAX(is_applicant) AS is_applicant
    GROUP BY id_request
    ORDER BY id_request DESC
```

I left out id since it is probably irrelevant.

I left out id_user and id_status; perhaps you want `MAX(id_user)`?  The issue is, if there could be two users or two statuses, which one do you want?

If you do need `id`, then see tag [greatest-n-per-group].

Comment: if there are two rows that have the same id_request value and also is_user (is_applicant is always 1 or 0 ), then only the row with is_applicant = 1 is displayed.

If there are multiple rows with the same id_request but different is_user, then all these rows will be displayedTL:DR - there will always be only one row with the same id_request value and the same id_user value (vic. comparison of both tables).

Comment: Update your example to show those cases.